# 1&1 web hosting not reading my .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-hosting, shared-hosting

It seems that my web host (1&1) is not reading my `.htaccess` file.

I tried configuring my `.htaccess` file to prevent file access via the web browser, specifically all files with the following extensions: `.txt`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.pdf`, `.xlsx`, `.xls`, `.doc`, `.docx`, `.eps`, `.gif`, `.png`.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
#DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

# 1und1 needed for php extensionless redirect.
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /relative/web/path/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization}  !^$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.ltd [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.ltd.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt|php|html|css|js)$ /messageforcurious [L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(txt|jpg|jpeg|pdf|xlsx|xls|doc|docx|eps|gif|png)$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#php_value register_globals 0
```

How do I achieve what I want? Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `.htaccess` file is readable by 1&1, but there is an easier way to block access to all files than what you are doing.

If you truly want to block all people from visiting your website - which is what blocking all files will do - you can make your .htaccess into:

```
Deny from all
```

Otherwise, you can do this, which will allow only some files to be accessed (in this case, only `.html` files):

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
  Allow from YOUR_IP_ADDRESS
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

For more reading, I'd look at [this 1&1 overview of their `.htaccess` file](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/htaccess-c37776/denyallow-access-to-your-website-files-a773577.html)

**Note:** I am entirely unsure of what your `index.php` redirects are doing above, since it seems that you want them to go to `/messageforcurious`. I'd remove those `index.php` redirects since it seems you don't want them.